Simulation-based proof of IKNP protocol(OT extension) for malicious adversary
I'm reading the well-known IKNP protocol for OT extension. In section 3.1, they give proofs for malicious Sender and semi-honest Receiver. I'm very confused about the proof for malicious Sender($S^*$). They say:

It is easy to verify that the joint distribution of $(\rho; s^*;Q)$, the values $(y_{j,0}; y_{j,1})$ and all values of $H$ queried by $S^*$ in the ideal process is identical to the corresponding distribution in the real process.

I have no idea why it's identical. So in my opinion, what they do in Simulator is choosing some random $(\rho; s^*;Q)$ and just feeding them to $S^*$. But I think malicious $S^*$ may ignore the messages fed, and arbitrarily give some.
So can I think that the distribution is identical just because $S^*$ is always arbitrarily give messages both in the real and ideal world. But I think it is not so simple.
The concrete construction of Simulator is as follows:

And in addition, are there some formal proofs of simple OT for malicous adversary for reference? I want to learn more examples.
Thank you in advance.

In this case, the Sender is malicious and the Receiver is honest. So we argue that the Sender can't learn anything about $r$. The crucial observation is that in IKNP protocol the Sender's $Q$'s column is like one-time pad. The $Q$'s column is like $\mathbf q^i \oplus \mathbf r$. Every $\mathbf q^i$ is independently randomness, so Q is random.
By this observation, we can choose a random $Q$ to feed the Sender. So both in real and ideal world the Sender get a random $Q$.
As for $\mathbf s$, which confused me. The security definition said $\forall \mathcal A, \exists \mathcal S$. So when we construct $\mathcal S$, we know $\mathcal A$'s code. So we know what messages the Sender send first.
So the proof makes sense.

And at last I want to ask if the last step (call the Trusted party, and output what $S^$ output) can be omitted, because in the real protocol the $S^$ has no output and this contribute nothing to its transcripts. I think it can be omitted. Am I right?
